# Why i am getting 9 as max() when there are numbers>9 in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote a code in Python to print the minimum and maximum value of user input. If I input the number 0 to 15, I would expect `max()` to return 15 and `min()` to return 0. However, `max()` returns 9:

```
i = (input().split(" "))
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

print(min(i))
# 0
print(max(i))
# 9
```

Why doesn't `max(i)` return 15?

Comment: `input numbers` - Convert to int first? If you compare strings, `'9'>'10'`

Comment: Just show your full code to help you. if you use for example this list `i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 34]` you won't have any problem

Answer (score 1):

If you check out your list `i`, you will see that the digits you entered are stored as strings, whereas you want to evaluate them based on their numeric value. Python is able to calculate the maximum value of strings, too (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-2-compare-string-and-int-why-do-lists-compare-as-greater-than-n) for more information).

You can fix this by explicitly transforming your input to integers:

```
i = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]

print(max(i))
print(min(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this.

```
i = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

print(min(i))
print(max(i))
```